# React how to re-render a placeholder on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app is fetching new data from the server every time a button is clicked. It also loads fresh data when the page is loaded using `componentDidMount` This is then displayed on my input box placeholder using `placeholder={this.state.response}`.

I would like to re-render the placeholder content with the updated data from the server.

**Home.js**

```js
export default class Home extends Component {
  state = {

    response: ''
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.chunk }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }



  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/password-api');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 8, offset: 2 }}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input className="password-area" type="textarea" name="text" id="exampleText" placeholder={this.state.response}/>
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 8, offset: 2 }}>
              <button onClick={this.callApi} id="get-pass-button" className="button">
                Generate Password
              </button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When the state is updated , the page will be rendered again

Comment: you need to update the state after calling callApi on button click, similar to what you did in componentDidMount

Comment: `this.setState({ ...this.state, response: res.chunk });` Did you try this?

Comment: @Abinthaha need not include ```...this.state``` as this.setState automatically merges the state.

Comment: @Vibhanshu: yeah, I was trying to say, the state will be replaced with response only. If there are other keys, then it will be deleted if spread operator no used.

Comment: @Abinthaha No all the other keys remain when you call the setState. It just adds/updated the new key in the state object as applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder is bound to `this.state.response`, hence it will update whenever this particular piece of state is changed. The placeholder **react**s to the the state change.

Your `componentDidMount()` calls `callApi()` and `.then()` sets the state using it's return value.

Your `onClick` does not do anything with the return value of`callApi()`. A solution **could** look like this.

```
handleClick = () => {
   this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.chunk }))
};
```

And in your `render()` method:

```
<button 
   onClick={this.handleClick} 
    id="get-pass-button" 
    className="button"
>
    Generate Password
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. 
Simple and clear explanation. Congo (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Add `handlePassButtonClick` method in component as follows:

```
export default class Home extends Component {


 state = {

    response: ''
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi()
      .then(res => this.setState({ response: res.chunk }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }



  callApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/password-api');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

    return body;
  };

  handlePassButtonClick = async () => {
    const response = await this.callApi();
    this.setState({ response });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 8, offset: 2 }}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input className="password-area" type="textarea" name="text" id="exampleText" placeholder={this.state.response}/>
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col sm="12" md={{ size: 8, offset: 2 }}>
              <button onClick={this.handlePassButtonClick} id="get-pass-button" className="button">
                Generate Password
              </button>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And attach `handlePassButtonClick` on button click.

Comment: Thanks, btw how important is `await` and `async ()` in the `handlePassButtonClick` function?

Comment: await and async are features that were introduced with ES6. Before that "promises" were used. I wont be able to explain it here in the comments. You should reasearch the terms.